# Discord.net voice channel ConnectAsync() error : A SlashCommandExecuted handler is blocking the gateway task

Tags: c#, discord.net

I want to make music bot

So, I made

```
public async Task SlashCommandHandler(SocketSlashCommand command)
        {
            if (command.User.IsBot) return;

            if (command.Data.Name.Equals("music"))
            {
                SocketGuildUser guildUser = command.User as SocketGuildUser;
                IVoiceChannel voiceChannel = guildUser.VoiceChannel;

                if (voiceChannel == null)
                {
                    await command.Channel.SendMessageAsync("X");
                    // TODO: Send error embed
                    return;
                }

                string? url = null;

                foreach (SocketSlashCommandDataOption option in command.Data.Options)
                {
                    if (option.Name.Equals("url"))
                    {
                        url = (string)option.Value;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(url);

                var audioClient = await voiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
                //handler is blocking the gateway task

                await SendAsync(audioClient, url);
            }
        }

        private Process? CreateStream(string path)
        {
            return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg",
                Arguments = $"-hide_banner -loglevel panic -i \"{path}\" -ac 2 -vol 512 -f s16le - ar 48000 pipe:1",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            });
        }

        private async Task SendAsync(IAudioClient client, string path)
        {
            // Create FFmpeg using the previous example
            using (var ffmpeg = CreateStream(path))
            using (var output = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream)
            using (var discord = client.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed))
            {
                try { await output.CopyToAsync(discord); }
                finally { await discord.FlushAsync(); }
            }
        }
    }
```

this

And Debug this, I get

```
00:35:48 Gateway     A SlashCommandExecuted handler is blocking the gateway task.
00:36:00 Gateway     A SlashCommandExecuted handler has thrown an unhandled exception.:
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.ConnectAudioAsync(UInt64 channelId, Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.ConnectAudioAsync(UInt64 channelId, Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketVoiceChannel.ConnectAsync(Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)
   at {Bot name}.EventListener.SlashCommandListener.SlashCommandHandler(SocketSlashCommand command) in {Project Path}\SlashCommandListener.cs:line 50
   at Discord.EventExtensions.InvokeAsync[T](AsyncEvent`1 eventHandler, T arg)
   at Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.TimeoutWrap(String name, Func`1 action)
```

this error at console

code at line:50 is

```
await voiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
```

this

I want to

1. get command author
2. get command's option(name is 'url')
3. get author's voice channel and join channel
4. send voice

let me know how to fix this error and if you teach me how to write code simple and neatly, I will very thanks to you